# Renderer won't render texture

Tags: java, libgdx

One of my object in the world won't be render on the screen.
I try a lot of things to understand the problem.
I have no idea where the problem is.

The world's code is there :

http://pastebin.com/Q4r6p0kf

And the render code :

http://pastebin.com/9ChYgCgQ

The problem is that the TailSnake won't render.

Comment: You have to set the SpriteBatchs projectionMatrix: `batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined)`. Also if you use camera you don't need ppuX and ppuY, camera does this thing for you. So if your cameras viewport is 80 units wide and the screen is 1600 pixels wide, the camera treats one unit as 20 pixels.

Comment: @Springrbua I do exactly how you said, nothing change and the application is slower.

Comment: How is it slower? What did you change?

Comment: @Springrbua In the `WorlController()` method I add `spritebatch.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined)` after the initialization of the spritebatch
and the main loop is longer than always

Comment: Set that in the constructor of `WorldRenderer`, directly after calling `new Spritebatch`. Also you can delete the ppuX and ppuY stuff.